# Get ECMAScript 5 Intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, ecmascript-5

Are there any known solutions to supporting ECMA 5 features in Visual Studio's Intellisense?

For example, it would be nice to have `Object.create()` and `Object.defineProperty()` as well as all of the new methods and functions on the native types.

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice, you can vote on the connect site for this feature to be implemented in vNext.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, good idea: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2206709-extend-javascript-intellisense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the developer preview of Visual Studio 11, and much of ECMAScript 5 is supported by Intellisense. I don't see solutions for support in VS 2010, so I guess the answer is: Wait for VS 11.